# Android Material Date Range Picker - How to change the text color of only the selected range dates?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-components-android, android-datepicker

I am attempting to reproduce this style with the [Material Range Date Picker](https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android#date-range-pickers):

[Calendar date picker with all the selected days in white textColor. The unselected days have a black textColor][image: 2]

This is what I have been able to achieve so far:

[Calendar date picker with only the selected boundary days in white textColor. The unselected days have a black textColor and the days within the selected boundaries are in black as well][image: 3]

```
  <style name="MyMaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/MyMaterialCalendarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyMaterialCalendarStyle"  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="rangeFillColor">@color/dark_green</item>
    <item name="daySelectedStyle">@style/MyDaySelectedStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDaySelectedStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day.Selected">
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/white</item>
  </style>
```

Apparently the `colorOnSurface` attribute sets the textColor for all days in the calendar and `daySelectedStyle` attribute sets the textColor only for the pair of final and initial days.

Is there a way to make the textColor of days between the start and end date white while keeping the text color of the unselected days black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is no direct way to do that. But you can edit the source code to achieve this.

> daySelectedStyle attribute sets the textColor only for the pair of final and initial days.

If you see the source code of [RangeDateSelector](https://github.com/DrHowdyDoo/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/RangeDateSelector.java#:%7E:text=%40Override-,public%20Collection%3CLong%3E%20getSelectedDays()%20%7B,%7D,-%40Override), you can see that the `getSelectedDays()` method only adds the start and end date.

[image: RangeDateSelector]

You can change the logic to include all the dates between the two selected dates.

For example, you can add this code in between the two if statements :

```
if (selectedStartItem != null && selectedEndItem != null) {
  Long l = selectedStartItem + 86401000;
  for (; l < selectedEndItem;) {
    selections.add(l);
    l = l + 86401000;
  }
}
```

The function will look like this :

[image: VScode]

The coloring part is executed in the [MonthAdapter.java](https://github.com/DrHowdyDoo/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MonthAdapter.java#:%7E:text=currently%20selected%20dates.-,if%20(dateSelector%20!%3D%20null)%20%7B,%7D,-%7D)

Final Result :

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: 86401000 is the approximate of a day in milliseconds (Long) right?

Very clever solution @DrHowdyDoo! Thanks a lot! +1